# What keys / "switches" are available for Alternate Pointer Actions?

Tags: keyboard, mouse

I would like to use a convenient keyboard shortcut for the context menu that is typically accessed by right clicking. Instructions for updating are here:

https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/mac-help/mchl7b437b35/mac

> To change the name or action assigned to a key, switch or facial expression, double-click the item in the list, or select it, click the Action pop-up menu , then follow the onscreen instructions.

Here is that dialog:

[image]

Clicking on the <kbd>⌥ Option</kbd> and then <kbd>F12</kbd> while right clicking brings up :

[image]

But which keys are permitted?  I tried <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd><kbd>;</kbd> and see:

[image]

(Note that <kbd>F11</kbd>/<kbd>F12</kbd> *are* possible - but they're a bit of a stretch for my hands so I was looking for something closer to home row.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not going to be able to assign a complex keyboard shortcut to the Accessibility/Alternate Control Method.  The reason for this is to *simplify* the process of right clicking, not to remap it to something else.

From [Apple Support:](https://www.apple.com/accessibility/mac/mobility/)

> We build powerful assistive technologies into Mac to give people with physical limitations more ways to be creative and productive. Switch Control lets you navigate what’s on your screen with a single tap. And a range of settings let you adjust interaction sensitivities for an experience that works for you.

What this is looking for a a whole different device (like a key switch device) that where the user presses a button, it will be mapped to something else.  You can use the function keys, but you'll have to un-map them first (<kbd>F11</kbd> and <kbd>F12</kbd> aren't mapped, so they're "available.")

> ... they're a bit of a stretch for my hands so I was looking for something closer to home row.

Finding something on the home row is really not feasible.

- <kbd>⌥ Option</kbd> and any of the charachterss on the home row are already bound to unicode characters:  åß∂ƒ©˙∆˚¬…
- <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>⌥ Option</kbd> as well: ÅÍÎÏ˝ÓÔÒÚÆ
- You may have some luck with <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd><kbd>⌥ Option</kbd> and assigning it a shortcut, but is this really easier than a single keypress like <kbd>F11</kbd>?

You could "make" a separate device with a USB or Bluetooth Ten Key (Number Pad) and with [USB Overdrive](https://www.usboverdrive.com/) or [ControllerMate](https://www.orderedbytes.com/controllermate/) program one of the keys of the keypad as either right click or left click.

Comment: Nice explanation thx